# How do I use a serial terminal with a FreeBSD server?

Tags: terminal, freebsd, serial-port, putty, getty

I have been experimenting with an RS-232 null modem cable and am curious to know how one would allow FreeBSD to use a serial port as a terminal, like in the days of the PDP-11 where all users had dumb terminals connected to the computer via serial connections. I wish to do the same with a headless FreeBSD machine with a serial cable running to my main PC which is using PuTTY to communicate over the serial port. Before you ask why I don't use SSH for the same purpose, I prefer this type of connection because if the network were to go down I would still be able to log into the server and see what exactly is happening, whereas if the same situation occurred with SSH I would be mostly out of luck, if that makes any sense at all. I have seen other similar questions with answers pointing to `screen` and `minicom` but these seem to be for fulfilling the role of PuTTY on the BSD side, which is not what I want here. What I want is a serial port configured at a specific baud rate with `getty` running on it, etc. as if it were an actual terminal.

To answer the question of what version of `init` I am running, I am using FreeBSD 10.3, and I haven't changed anything at the system level so it's running the default BSD-style `init` that uses rc scripts.

Comment: In 2017 you don't use serial terminals. If you have to use a real (physical) one - and that is more costly than an Ethernet connection -, you should read many things. Start with http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/ ; in the 1980s I remembered spending  a lot of time to connect a terminal to a Sun workstation. Don't want that again

Comment: Thanks for the info. I understand the obsolescence of what I am trying to do here, but I expected that a system that evolved from a system that basically relied on serial terminals would at least have some support for them.

Comment: You do have all the support for that, but there are lots of tuning involved, different cables, and so on. See `getty` & `termcap`. But believe me, it is a nightmare. See also `termios` and `stty`.

Comment: Launching the `getty` processes is the responsibility of init. So to start with, tell us what version of init you're using.

Comment: See https://linux.die.net/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO.html

Comment: This freebsd guide looks relevant: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/term.html - you may need to edit `/etc/ttys`. Have you got any confirmation that the serial driver is working?

Comment: Thank you for the info! I have been able to send information out via the serial port, and get information back as well, so yes the serial driver appears to be working.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, most of the stuff in that "TTY demystified" document has nothing to do with actual serial terminals in particular. I also don't see what the big issue in starting a getty would be, if you have an actual serial port (a fixed one, I could assume the usual labeling issues if you had multiple USB serial ports)

Comment: @nkeck72, It would _really_ be much easier to answer your question if you were clear about what system you're using: FreeBSD or Linux, and if latter, which distribution.

Comment: @ilkkachu sorry, I wrote this forgetting that my server now runs FreeBSD (it ran Linux until about late 2016).

Comment: The instructions for editing `/etc/ttys` looked pretty clear to me. Have you tried it?

Comment: I am away from my server right now, but yes I will try it when I get back to it.

Comment: Do you have the right cable? Just because you can plug both ends in doesn't mean it's going to work. "Null modem" and "serial cable" are very different things. Actually, "serial cable" can mean several different things. Do yourself a favor, get a multimeter and check how the pins are wired first. Also, don't connect the cable when both machines are running (there is a non-zero chance to fry the motherboards that way).

Comment: I tried it, and it did indeed work. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the /etc/ttys file.  It's kind of like gettytab in Linux.  There's one line for each... terminal line.  The "ttyuX" are for serial ports (different drivers have different device names, consult man pages, eg  [`man uart`](http://man.freebsd.org/uart)  for physical serial ports .

What you need to do to enable them is to change the "off" (or "onifconsole") to "on", and notify init by running "init q" as root.

Remember that differently from protocols like SSH or TELNET, serial ports don't have a protocol to negotiate terminal type and size.  So, at minimum, run resizewin(1) (http://man.freebsd.org/resizewin) from your shell initialization script.  Otherwise the default terminal size (as visible in "stty -a") will be zero, and this will result in things like shell line editing, less(1) or vi(1) output to be badly messed up.